# View block listing nodes with lower/higher Nodequeue position

Tags: views, nodes

I'm trying to build up two blocks for nodes with a Nodequeue position, one above the node listing nodes with lower Nodequeue position and one below the node listing nodes. It should look like a list of linked titles and a full node display in between:

- Node A (Linked title only, Nodequeue position: 1)
- Node B (Linked    title only, Nodequeue position: 2)
- Node C (Current full node display, Nodequeue position: 3)
- Node D (Linked title only, Nodequeue position: 4)
- Node E (Linked title only, Nodequeue position: 5)

Clicking the title of "Node D" should result in this:

- Node A (Linked title only, Nodequeue position: 1)
- Node B (Linked title only, Nodequeue position: 2)
- Node C (Linked title only, Nodequeue position: 3)
- Node D (Current full node display, Nodequeue position: 4)
- Node E (Linked title only, Nodequeue position: 5)

I've tried Contextual Filters in Views, but couldn't find a way to limit the list to nodes with lower/higher Nodequeue position.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I would say take the query from view and implemnt a  page to render above results where you would like to display full node based on nodeid sent in URL...

Comment: Right, but I couldn't find a way to compare the positions in the filter section, it only offers a static number for comparison. I need something like "Nid:position < current node Nid:position", not "Nid:position < e.g. 5"

Answer (score 0):

For sorting the nodes according to their position in a nodequeue follow these steps:

- Add a relationship "Nodequeue: Queue".
- You might want to select "Limit to one or more queues (recommended)" from the options provided and select appropriate nodequeue.
- Save.
- Click "add" in the sort criteria. Select "Nodequeue: Position"
  [image: snapshot]
- Select ascending/descending depending on the positions.
- Save.

And as for the other requirement that you posted "Current full node display"; I think this could be handled with adding the fields in the view, and controlling their display using JS.

Comment: This would do the sorting, right, but I'd like to avoid JS on this to preserve SEO friendlyness.